# Current Location not working

Tags: ios, swift, gps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am very new to both iOS developing and using the google maps sdk. I am using Xcode for my current project. I have added my API keys in the appropriate place.

So far I have this:

import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func loadView() {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(36.2108, longitude: -81.6774, zoom: 15.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    if let mylocation = mapView.myLocation {
        print("User's location: \(mylocation)")
    } else {
        print("User's location is unknown")
    }
    self.view = mapView
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain
    mapView.indoorEnabled = true
    let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    mapView.padding = mapInsets

    //Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    //let marker = GMSMarker()
    //marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.2108, longitude: -81.6774)
    //marker.title = "ASU"
    //marker.snippet = "Boone, NC"
    //marker.map = mapView
    }

}
```

My problem is that when I run the app using the simulator, it doesn't show my current gps location anywhere. It does successfully take me to the specified coordinates, it zooms correctly, and it shows the map as the typography map.

So my questions:

**What am I doing wrong thats making my current location not show up? (it never asks to have permission)**

**How can I make my map appear in the background? Like I added the padding to the top so i could add a button through the storyboard but the button did not show up.**

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you requested "when in use" authorisation and added the appropriate key to your info.plist

Comment: not a clue how to do that! so no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location on the simulator does not always work, you can:

1. try to reset the content of the simulator by Simulator > Reset content and settings
2. change simulator
3. make sure you have added custom lat and long in the simulator Simulator > Debug > Location > Custom location

Comment: My problem with the current location thing is that I have made the test case and it always prints that the users location is unknown!

Answer (score 0):

The problem why there is no padding in the mapView is because you are setting the mapView to be shown as your main view (self.view = mapView) and due to this map is covering the area of the whole screen.

Try to add a subView with padding from the main View and then assign the map View to your subView. Like this -

```
let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-100))

subView = mapView

self.view.addSubview(subView)
```

Also for the location issue try to set a default location for your xcode. Refer this for details on how to set location during runtime.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/simulating_location_on_run.html